# KeyError in multiIndex

Tags: pandas

Following code gives me keyerror, what's the right way to access multiindex dataframe, WITHOUT using functions like `loc` etc.?

```
arrays = [[1, 1, 2, 2], ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue']]
multi_idx=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('number', 'color'))
dfm=pd.DataFrame({"hello":[1,2,3,4]},index=multi_idx)
print(dfm[1]['red'])
```

Comment: `dfm.xs(1).xs('red')` is one way.

Comment: @wwnde am looking for answer without using functions, possible?

Answer (score 0):

Please Try

```
 dfm.query('color == "red"')
```

or slice rows.slice(None) selects all the contents of that level. It excempts the specifying of deeper levels. Slice(None) implies them.

```
dfm.loc[(slice(None),'red'),:]
```